# function in catch block immediately invoked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to raise an errorBoundary if an API call does not return a 200 but the raiseErrorBoundary is invoked immediately in catch block when the API call is called, how can I make it so it is invoked only when an error has been thrown?

```
export const downgradeAPICall = (raiseErrorBoundary) => {
    return fetch('http://localhost:42005/Upgrade/Downgrade', {
        method: 'POST'
    }).then(res => {
        if(res.status != 200){
            throw new Error("An error has occured during API request!")
        } else {
            window.location.reload()
        }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
        raiseErrorBoundary()
    })
}
```

Comment: Ehm, isn't if(res.status == 200){ condition wrong? 200=OK and you throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`200` is an "OK" status response.  Right now you throw an error if it's successful so it will probably throw an error no matter what the way you've written it. Instead you probably want `if(res.status !== 200)`

*(also "occurred" was misspelled as "occured")*

```
export const downgradeAPICall = (raiseErrorBoundary) => {
    return fetch('http://localhost:42005/Upgrade/Downgrade', {
        method: 'POST'
    }).then(res => {
        if(res.status !== 200){
            throw new Error("An error has occurred during API request!")
        } else {
            window.location.reload()
        }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
        raiseErrorBoundary()
    })
}
```